# How to use entity framework dbcontext in data layer than in the controller

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, backend

I've created a .NET/Angular project with Entity Framework.
Actually, I am with Entity Framework Core 7.0.1 in CodeFirst and .NET 6.0

I have this structure :

- App.Controllers
- App.Model
- App.Business

I want to use the DbContext only in the data layer (App.Business) and be able to use my DbContext like this :

[Documentation of entity framework for Include() fonction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh5kr.png)

Actually, the injection dependency inject the DbContextOptionsBuilder in the Entity Framework context class :

[DbContextOptionsBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MCRj.png)

And I can use it like this and like all the examples that I found :

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R39p.png)

The problem is that I found any documentation who explain how to use the DbContext this way.
All tutorial I Found use the DbContext in the Controller, and that's the same for the documentation by Microsoft...

So, how can I modify the injection of dependencies to the data layer and not the Controller ?

I've tried to use a IRepository classe and use it into the Controller but without succes.
I've tried to compare my code with other project on github but anything was like I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more info and code of what you've tried and failed?

Comment: I've created an Repository class with this constructor (who heritate of IRepository class ) : 

        public Repository(EFCoreContext context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
            this.Entities = context.Set<T>();
        }

And use this class in my Controller :

//private static PostBusiness pb;
        private readonly IRepository<Post> _repository;

        public PostController(IRepository<Post> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

Comment: You should make the contoller class dependent on the repository via interface and register the repository interface and class in the DI map. And call repository methods from the controller.